# "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 278540 into shape (256,128,3,3)" Conversion YOLOv3 .weights to .pb

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo, darknet

I have trained a YOLO v3 Object Detection Model. To incorporate into my flutter application I am trying to convert it to .tflite, with .pb needed as intermediate. I am getting this error with every github repo I have tried. (A few linked below)

Error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 278540 into shape (256,128,3,3)

Following is what my classes.names file looks like:

[image]

I have just 2 classes. I am unable to convert. Can someone please help?

Link to my weights and config file:

- Weights: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dqKHqzaqhHuxO5wuW9mgIeCbor9NyTMh/view?usp=sharing
- Cfg: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_e607nkMTObKlYUCQc8IZtXMsUKJ_aab/view?usp=sharing

A few repos that I have tried:

- https://github.com/benjamintanweihao/YOLOv3
- https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite
- https://github.com/mystic123/tensorflow-yolo-v3?fbclid=IwAR0ojevKaFH2EIQvxmMfSgLPm9Mz9V_e_5E621BEckgGb-FpvuS7ZLcM7NI
- https://github.com/peace195/tensorflow-lite-YOLOv3
- https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects
- https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2
- https://github.com/mystic123/tensorflow-yolo-v3

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](https://github.com/haroonshakeel/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) repo for converting my custom YOLO v4 tiny model to TensorFlow. I too faced the same error. When I dug deeper into code, by default the code in `./core/utils.py` is taking `./data/classes/coco.names` in line no. 78. I gave the path to my own `obj.names` and it worked. Please give the path of your `obj.names` or *.names`in line no. 78 of`./core/utils.py`.

Sample:

```
with open("path/to/your/obj.names", 'r') as data:
```

Or edit `__C.YOLO.CLASSES = "path/to/your/obj.names"` in `config.py` on line no. 14.

Comment: Did you mean to link to a fork of the original project?